# Getting the input box 100% even width inside a fieldset element

Tags: html, css, fieldset

How can I get my input box positioned evenly inside my fieldset element at 100% width with respect to my fieldset?

As it stands now, it seems **the input box is overflowing** on the right out of the fieldset and im not sure why?

Here's an image of the problem (ie10):
[image]

Here is the markup:

```css
fieldset {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 300px
}

label {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Subscription info</legend>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are facing is the default style that is computed on `input` by your browser. The browser adds padding and a border to the `<input>` element.

As you are setting `width:100%;` on the input, if you add the default padding and border, it renders wider than the container and therefore overflows.

You can solve this by adding : `box-sizing:border-box;` on the `input` so padding and border are contained in the 100% width.

```css
fieldset {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 300px
}

label {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Subscription info</legend>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</fieldset>
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) about the `box-sizing` property.

Comment: Works 100% and I will gladly accept. Thank you Tiki.

Comment: @JasonKelly Glad I could help! I just updated the fiddle with the different prefix needed for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for before. But if you remove the padding it doesn't get cut off.

```
fieldset {
width: 300px
}
```